# CSS Undoing a height: auto; declaration

Tags: css, height, image

I am adding a small bit of code to an existing word press theme.  The area where the new code is is covered by this in the style sheet:

```
#content img {
    height: auto; }
```

Within my bit of code which is executed within plugin/widget, I retrieve information on thumbnail images and then display them within an img tag.  Depending on the size of the image I add either a height or a width attribute.  (the width works fine btw).  When it comes to the height attribute it ignores it due to the height: auto declaration.

My smaller box within #content is #CPGimage.  I can overwrite height, but do not know the appropriate height value until I read the image.  (if the max desired width is 100 and the max desired height is 100 image is 100x200 I add an height attribute to the img tag of 100).

Is there a way to undo the height declaration under #content or somehow set something that tells it to get the height from the img tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers.  What I ended up doing was using in-line css on the img tag with this:

```
img style="width: 100px;" ....
```

before I was doing something like
    img height="100" ....

The overall problem was that I write the img tag from a php script so when writing the tag I know the width or height components I want but since there are several img tags and there may be different size requirements the info could not be written to the css ahead of time.

The inline css style taxes precedence where the img height html method does not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
height:inherit
```

? HTH

Comment: This didn't work.  The problem is that the height in the outer box was already set to auto and using inherit would just get that auto value.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to limit the maximum height of the image, have you tried using [`max-height`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp)?

Comment: This wouldn't work because I don't know what the max-height until execution time... it is the php script which knows the max-height.  Therefore needed something in the img tag which is written by the php script.

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting width or height attributes use css:

```
document.getElementById('myImg').style.height = '32px';
```

or if you have jQuery :

```
$('#myImg').css({ width: 32 });
```

Comment: If it would work without javascript, it works on nearly every browser .(except css is switched off, but then it doesn't really matter)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to ... somehow set something that tells it to get the
>   height from the img tag?

If you are using jQuery, you can grab the `img` height like so

```
var h = $('#content img').height();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ELaeV/